# JSON data to leaflet's javascript library

Tags: ajax, json, leaflet, geojson

I've read alot about geojson but I'm wondering if there is alternative methods. Below is how i add my current points of interest:

```
     var map = L.map('map').setView([39.76, -98.5], 4);
 L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png').addTo(map);



var marker = L.marker([33.1958, -117.3786]).addTo(map);

marker.bindPopup("<b>Trainers</b><br>Oceanside, CA.").openPopup();
var marker = L.marker([38.9125, -75.4283]).addTo(map);
marker.bindPopup("<b>Trainers</b><br>Milford, DE.").openPopup();
var marker = L.marker([41.26129, -95.93262]).addTo(map);
marker.bindPopup("<b>Trainers</b><br>Omaha, NE.").openPopup();
var marker = L.marker([25.77516, -80.2002]).addTo(map);
marker.bindPopup("<b>Trainers</b><br>Miami, FL.").openPopup();

//map.on('moveend', onMapMove);


//On mouse over will display the coordinates
map.on('mousemove', function (e) {
        var latlng = e.latlng;
        document.getElementById('latlong').innerHTML = latlng;}, 
    this);
```

Here's my ajax:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){ 
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',     
      dataType: "json",
      url: '<?php echo matry::base_to('tests/map_it');?>',
      success: function (data) 
      {
         alert($.parseJSON(data[0]).id);
        $('#alerts').html(data);
        data[0].id

      }

      });
    });
```

Here is my php:

```
$mapit = sql::results("Select * from event.ACS.trainer where inactive is null or inactive=0");
foreach ($mapit as $row)
{
    $return[] = json_encode($row, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
}
echo json_encode($return);
```

my json object is returning all the correct data that i'll need. I'm now stuck on implementing my points of interest into their javascript libraries.

Here is my json output:

```
"{"id":19385,"first":"KIRLY","last":"MAELLI","trainer_address1":"19 NE 111TH COT","trainer_address2":null,"CITY":"MIMI","STATE":"FL","trainer_zip":"379","trainer_phone":"(-6490","trainer_fax":null,"trainer_cell":"(-6490","website_trainer_id":115,"trainer_email":"MOBA@YAHOO.COM","trainer_group":"","inactive":null}",
"{"id":19386,"first":"CHY","last":"MEH","trainer_address1":"1014 ROAD","trainer_address2":null,"CITY":"MIORD","STATE":"DE","trainer_zip":"63","trainer_phone":"","trainer_fax":null,"trainer_cell":"(-8811","website_trainer_id":118,"trainer_email":"CAH@AOL.COM","trainer_group":"","inactive":null}",
```

Comment: What is the question? Can you be more specific?

Comment: Thanks for responding: I need to learn how to create markers in the success function of my ajax call.

Comment: The data in the JSON you print does not contain coordinates. Do you have those in the database? Otherwise you'll need to geocode the addresses, for example at http://geocoder.us/

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the results of your sql query to GeoJSON, server side. This would be a good idea, since any client that understands GeoJSON can use it then, and Leaflet will interpret the data for you.

Creating a GeoJSON feature collection is not more complicated than creating "ordinary" JSON.
See [the specs](http://www.geojson.org/geojson-spec.html#examples) for an example.

```
{
   "type": "FeatureCollection",
   "features": [
       { "type": "Feature", 
         "properties": { "title": "Trainers", "placename": "Oceanside, CA."}, 
          "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -117.3786, 33.1958 ] } },
       { "type": "Feature", 
         "properties": { "title": "Trainers", "placename": "Milford, DE."}, 
         "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -75.4283, 38.9125 ] } }
    ]
}
```

(Note that the lat/lon pairs are in reverse order compared to leaflet)

In PHP, you'll need to fill arrays and dicts and `json_encode` them.
Untested guesstimate (but I doubt it's far off):

```
array('type' => 'FeatureCollection', 
      'features' => array(
           array( "type" => "Feature",
                  "properties" => array("title" => "Trainers", 
                                        "placename" => "Oceanside, CA."),
                  "geometry" => array( "type" => "Point", 
                                  "coordinates" => array( -117.3786, 33.1958 ))),
           array( "type" => "Feature",
                  "properties" => array("title" => "Trainers", 
                                        "placename" => "Milford, DE."),
                  "geometry" => array( "type" => "Point", 
                                  "coordinates" => array( -75.4283, 38.9125 )))
       ))
```

When creating the GeoJSON layer in Leaflet, provide an `onEachFeature` function to create the popup with the feature data:

```
function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
    layer.bindPopup("<b>"+feature.properties.title +
                    "</b><br>"+feature.properties.placename);
}
```

(But alternatively, you can keep the server code as is, and create markers in the success function of your ajax call.)

Unsure if I'm stating the obvious, but it helps to use a dev toolbar in your browser when you want to debug this.

Comment: Thanks for the response flup, I'm uncertain on how to use my server code to create markers, this is how I would like to do it and down the line maybe convert to GeoJson. Thanks for taking the time to read and respond back. More help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I've added some more specifics

Comment: Still having a bit of trouble.

Comment: If i don't want to use geojson and I only want to go through my json object and pull address, city and stae. How would I go about it that way. Sorry for so many questions. Really trying to learn this here.

Comment: Additonally, I've added my json object data to my orignal post. Thanks for helping again.

Comment: You really do wish to use GeoJSON. The data will need transforming either in php or in javascript. Might as well do it near the source, plus it is easier to debug.